# How to smooth Disjunct constraints in a GDP in Pyomo if the value of the objective function exceeds a value?

Tags: pyomo

I am currently working on solving a GDP problem. The nature of this problem is GDP (Generalized Disjunctive Programming) because the decision variables involved are semi-continuous.

In this problem, the decision variables can either be zero or take values within certain upper and lower limits. I aim to minimize an objective function using these variables.

Ideally, I would like the objective function to have a value below a specified threshold. However, achieving this depends on the combination of variables, which is influenced by a parameter read from an Excel file. This parameter can vary, and at times, it may cause the semi-continuous variables I defined to be unable to maintain the objective function below the desired threshold.

In such cases, I intend to convert these semi-continuous variables to continuous variables. This adjustment is aimed at improving the chances of keeping the objective function below the desired threshold.

At the moment, the way I have made this change from continuous to semi-continuous variables is by deactivating the Disjunction.

I have tried the following example

```
from pyomo.environ import*
from pyomo.gdp import*

A=[1,2]
B=6 #This number is read from an Excel
LB = {1: 0, 2:0}
UB={1: 10, 2:10}
DUB={1: 5, 2:5}
DLB={1: 3, 2:3}

model = ConcreteModel()



def initials_bounds_rule(model,a):
    return(LB[a],UB[a])

model.x = Var(A, bounds=initials_bounds_rule)

model.obj = Objective(expr = (B- model.x[1]-model.x[2])**2)

def disyuncion_off_rule(d, a):
    m = d.model()
    d.c = Constraint(expr=model.x[a] == 0)

model.disyuncion_off = Disjunct(A, rule=disyuncion_off_rule)

def disyuncion_on_rule(d, a):
    m = d.model()
    d.c = Constraint(expr=inequality(DLB[a], model.x[a], DUB[a]))
model.disyuncion_on = Disjunct(A, rule=disyuncion_on_rule)

def Disyunciones_rule(m, a):
     return[model.disyuncion_off[a], model.disyuncion_on[a]]
model.Disyunciones = Disjunction(A, rule=Disyunciones_rule)

#Solver
xfrm = TransformationFactory('gdp.bigm')
xfrm.apply_to(model)

opt = SolverFactory('gurobi')
resultados = opt.solve(model)
#Convert semicontinuous variables to continuous by deactivating disjunction
if value(model.obj)>0:

    model.Disyunciones.deactivate()
    model.disyuncion_off.deactivate()
    model.disyuncion_on.deactivate()


    opt = SolverFactory('ipopt')
    resultados = opt.solve(model)
```

In this case the minimum is found with the semi-continuous variables.

```
x : Size=2, Index=x_index
Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
  1 :     0 :   3.0 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
  2 :     0 :   3.0 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
```

But if the parameter B is changed to 18 for example, I get the following:

```
WARNING: Loading a SolverResults object with a warning status into
model.name="unknown";
  - termination condition: infeasible
  - message from solver: Ipopt 3.11.1\x3a Converged to a locally
    infeasible point. Problem may be infeasible.
```

But the variables take the following values

```
x : Size=2, Index=x_index
Key : Lower : Value             : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
  1 :     0 : 8.986149869493252 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
  2 :     0 : 8.986149869493252 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
```

What I have done seems to "work", but it seems very clumsy. This way I only manage to eliminate the restrictions, but maybe it would be more correct to relax the constraints until the disjunctions have to be eliminated.

I would like to know if there are other ways of doing this.
Is there a way to create conditional disjunct or disjucnt with conditional constraints inside?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are better approaches....

First, I'm not sure if you can just "turn off" the disjunctions because you have already used them to transform the model and I don't use them enough to know if that transformation can be neatly undone.  You could probably do some experiments/print the resultant model to see...  Or perhaps somebody else will comment on that

You can make this model linear, which is always preferable.  You appear to be squaring the result just to get the deviation from zero, so a linear alternative is to just introduce another variable and use it to get the absolute value of the deviation from zero as shown below.

On the variable bounds, an alternative for your disjunction approach in which you "prefer" to have variables within the bounds, but will sacrifice that to get the objective as low as possible is to implement a penalty strategy in the objective.  You can introduce *another* variable to capture the overage/underage for each variable and just put a little weighted penalty on that and achieve the same end result....  I implemented a big-M constraint to get the indicator variable for "x == 0" to work, basically mimicking the disjunction, but with penalties for excursions.  The objective will be minimized, and a small penalty will be added to any overages/underages in the `x` variables.  Much cleaner, and can be done in 1 solve.

##### Code:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.gdp import *

A   = [1, 2]
B   = 4 # This number is read from an Excel
LB  = {1: 0, 2: 0}
UB  = {1: 10, 2: 10}
DUB = {1: 5, 2: 5}
DLB = {1: 3, 2: 3}
M = max(UB.values())

model = ConcreteModel()

def initials_bounds_rule(model, a):
    return (LB[a], UB[a])
model.x = Var(A, bounds=initials_bounds_rule)
model.x_zero = Var(A, domain=Binary)  # 1 if x[a] == 0
model.x_overage = Var(A, domain=NonNegativeReals, doc='amount of x that exceeds bounds')
model.obj_miss  = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals, doc='amount that |obj| misses zero')

model.obj = Objective(expr=model.obj_miss + 0.1 * sum(model.x_overage[a] for a in A))

# constrain the obj miss to the +/- of the expression to catch absolute value
model.C1 = Constraint(expr= model.obj_miss >= B - model.x[1] - model.x[2])
model.C2 = Constraint(expr= model.obj_miss >= -(B - model.x[1] - model.x[2]))

# constrain the overage for each x...
@model.Constraint(A)
def LB_excess(model, a):
    # the amount by which the LB is exceeded, or arbitrarily negative if x[a] is zero
    return model.x_overage[a] >= DLB[a] - model.x[a] - M * model.x_zero[a]

@model.Constraint(A)
def UB_excess(model, a):
    return model.x_overage[a] >= model.x[a] - DUB[a]

@model.Constraint(A)
def link(model, a):
    return model.x[a] <= (1 - model.x_zero[a]) * M


opt = SolverFactory("cbc")
resultados = opt.solve(model)
print(resultados)

model.x.display()
model.x_overage.display()
model.obj_miss.display()
```

##### Output:

```
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 0.0
  Upper bound: 0.0
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 8
  Number of variables: 7
  Number of binary variables: 2
  Number of integer variables: 2
  Number of nonzeros: 3
  Sense: minimize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  User time: -1.0
  System time: 0.0
  Wallclock time: 0.0
  Termination condition: optimal
  Termination message: Model was solved to optimality (subject to tolerances), and an optimal solution is available.
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 0
      Number of created subproblems: 0
    Black box: 
      Number of iterations: 0
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.00939488410949707
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

x : Size=2, Index=x_index
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      1 :     0 :   4.0 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
      2 :     0 :   0.0 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
x_overage : amount of x that exceeds bounds
    Size=2, Index=x_overage_index
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      1 :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
      2 :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
obj_miss : amount that |obj| misses zero
    Size=1, Index=None
    Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
    None :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
[Finished in 293ms]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply AirSquid. It solves the problem and also transforms the non-linear problem into a linear one. That's a plus.

There is one thing I don't understand in your code, what does @model.Constraint(A) do?

Comment: it is using a function decorator to make the constraints.  It isn't well documented, but it is equivalent to using a function-rule combo and it is making an instance of the constraint for every member of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

A semi-continuous variable x can be formulated directly as:

```
  L⋅δ ≤ x ≤ U⋅δ 
  δ ∈ {0,1}
```

No need to use GDP for this.

We can relax this using something like:

```
  L⋅δ ≤ x ≤ U⋅(δ+γ)
  δ+γ ≤ 1  
  δ,γ ∈ {0,1}
```

Here γ=1 would make x continuous between 0 and U.

For completeness, the following combinations can occur:

```
δ=0,γ=0 => x=0
δ=1,γ=0 => x∈[L,U]
δ=0,γ=1 => x∈[0,U]
```

Then write:

```
 min f + penalty⋅γ
 f ≤ threshold
 f = original objective function
```

Mathematical notation allows us to look at the problem at a higher abstraction level. I often prefer it to code to communicate models, especially when the code is not very structure-revealing.

Comment: Thank you for your answers @Erwin. It is a very simple and elegant way to solve the problem.